# Generating bridge method to resolve clashing methods with the same erasure

Tags: java, generics

Given:

```
interface Parent1
{
    default Parent1 apply(Consumer<Parent1> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
        return this;
    }
}

interface Parent2
{
    default Parent2 apply(Consumer<Parent2> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to declare `interface Child extends Parent1, Parent2` without triggering the following compiler error? `'apply(Consumer<? extends Parent2>)' in 'Scratch.Parent2' clashes with 'apply(Consumer<? extends Parent1>)' in 'Scratch.Parent1'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other`

I understand what the error means, and why type erasure leads to this problem. But is there any way to manually create bridge methods along the lines of:

```
interface Child extends Parent1, Parent2 {
    @Override
    default Child apply(Consumer<Child> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    default Parent1 apply(Consumer<Parent1> consumer) {
        return apply((Consumer<Child>) consumer);
    }

    @Override
    default Parent2 apply(Consumer<Parent2> consumer) {
        return apply((Consumer<Child>) consumer);
    }
}
```

So the following compiled code ends up getting generated after erasure?

```
interface Child extends Parent1, Parent2 {
    @Override
    default Child apply(Consumer consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this compiler error, or is it impossible to create an interface that extends Parent1 and Parent2?

PS: Using wildcards (e.g. `Consumer<? extends Parent1>` and `Consumer<? extends Parent2>`) does not help either.

**UPDATE**:

- There are multiple children of different types, so the parents cannot reference the child type.
- Here is the workaround I'm using for now:

I've moved all conflicting methods into a third interface (say Parent3):

```
interface Parent3<S>
{
  default S apply(Consumer<S> consumer);
}
```

where S is the self-type, and I make sure to only implement these methods in the child interface. So we end up with:

```
interface Child extends Parent1, Parent2, Parent3<Child>
{
  // Implement conflicting methods here
}
```

Comment: (strange, but the Eclipse compiler [2023-12] allows an interface extending both `Parent1` and `Parent2` - overriding the method(s) is not allowed)

Comment: Interestingly Kotlin compiles code like this successfully. Perhaps consider using Kotlin.

Comment: I think Java's rules are a bit overly strict in this case. The methods are still distinguishable even after type erasure, because their return types (which needs to be included in the `invokeinterface` instruction as part of the method descriptor) are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is, more or less, possible, but we need to unwrap some layers here.

### Is it a CameraGun or semantically related?

Right now you have the following situation: Two completely unrelated interfaces that each declare a method, whose signatures are identical. Or, if not identical, nearly identical. Forget, for a moment, that due to erasure they are *so* identical (differing only in the generics) that java can't make this work for you. Just consider the fact that these method signatures are *nearly* identical, on two types that are **utterly** unrelated.

So, what you have, then, is the equivalent of this:

```
public interface Camera {
  void shoot(Person p);
}

public interface Gun {
  void shoot(Person p);
}

// and with those established, you are attempting to...

class CameraGun implements Camera, Gun {
  void shoot(Person p) {
    // hoo boy I wonder what we are going to write here!
  }
}
```

So, there are only two options.

1. You really want a CameraGun: A single class that needs to implement a single method that does two **utterly** unrelated things somehow all at once, the exact same way a CameraGun would need to provide a single method that is to implement both the notion of taking a photographic image of a person, as well as murdering them, and **YOU SHOULD OBVIOUSLY BE RUNNING FOR THE HILLS HERE**. The only right answer is not to play this game. *Do not* write this class. The problem 'CameraGun?' is best answered by: "What?? No CameraGuns!".
2. This isn't a cameragun case: Your 2 unrelated `apply` methods aren't, in fact, unrelated. They semantically mean the exact same thing. Quite unlike that Camera/Gun scenario. For example, with the camera/gun scenario, it's more or less coincidence that both methods are even called `shoot`. The Camera could just as easily named that `void capture(Person p)`, but that name makes zero sense for the Gun interface. That's a tipoff that the CameraGun situation is, well, the first case. If that cannot be done here (no name that is appropriate for the one would ever be inappropriate for the other), then, this entire design is wrong.

So, the road splits here. You either have a CameraGun in which case you need to Stop. Right. Now.

Or, you have a '2 semantically equivalent concepts represented by method declarations; however, they are in types that are unrelated' case in which case we move on to...

### You need a common supertype

if the two `apply` methods are semantically related then *your code needs to reflect that fact*. Right now it does not, hence, your code is broken. The way to do this in java is to make a common type that captures this shared semantic meaning. Interfaces are allowed to extend another, and redefine what the semantic idea is behind one of the methods that your extension therefore 'adopts' - but you can't undefine one, nor can you change anything. You can only tighten definitions (the base interface may say: "Something festive will happen", and some interface that extends it nuances that with: "Confetti will happen. Which we all know is certainly festive.". The subinterface doesn't change that this method is to be implemented by doing something festive at all. It merely adds a compatible and more specific additional requirement.

That's what you must build here. Ah, but, the generics. Well, you need..

### `super`

Your code definition is just broken even before we get to the 'it does not compile' part. This:

```
default Parent1 apply(Consumer<Parent1> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
        return this;
    }
```

**Is just wrong**.

This is correct:

```
default Parent1 apply(Consumer<? super Parent1> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(this);
        return this;
    }
```

The difference is the `? super`. The point of this consumer is to consume `this`. Which a `Consumer<GrandParent>` can do just as well, as can a `Consumer<Object>`. There's no reason not to write that.

Once you've fixed that, you need..

### Generics 'self type' hack.

Java does not, unfortunately, have a self-type. The first thing you need to get into the habit of, is to accept that as fact. It cannot be truly fixed, only hacked around. That means having self-returning methods anytime hierarchy is relevant **is just wrong** and is a code style you need to stop using. I get that its enticing sometimes. But, here, given that type hierarchy *clearly* plays a role, having these methods return themselves is a really bad idea. Just go with `void`, calling code will just have to forego the convenience of being able to chain.

However, if self types are really needed, *sometimes*, you can hack it. This isn't without its problems and cannot be backwards compatibility applied, so, you have to think of it straight away. This is what it looks like:

```
interface Grandparent<G extends Grandparent<G>> {
  @SuppressWarnings({"all", "unchecked"})
  default G self() {
    return (G) this;
  }
}

interface Parent1 extends Grandparent<Parent1> {}

interface Parent2<P extends Parent2<P>> extends Grandparent<P> {}

class Child1 implements Parent2<Child1> {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Child1 c = new Child1();
  Child1 d = c.self();
  assert c == d;
 }
}
```

As you can see, this hack has various issues associated with it:

1. You must explcitly write the `self()` method, and it cannot be written without adding some `@SuppressWarnings`. At least, once you've done this, any other method no longer needs to dip into `@SW` territory; they can just call `self()` whenever needed.
2. Any subtypes in the hierarchy have to continue to kludge it up and add this weird `<X extends Self<X>>` stuff. You have to pre-decide if you're the final type in the hierarchy or not.
3. Even if you are, any implementations need to still write `class Foobar extends SelfHackeryType<Foobar>`.
4. Anybody using such instances see the generics and might go: Wtf is that doing there?

But, if you're willing to jump through all those hoops, you get what you want: You can call `child1.someSelfReturningMethod()` and that expression is typed 'Child1'. This means if 'Child1' has a method `setName` that you'd like to chain (it returns itself), and Grandchild1 (`extends Child1`) has `setBirthdate` (Child1 does not have this method), you can still write `new Grandchild1().setName("Jake").setBirthdate(someDate);` and have that 'work' - whereas without this hack it would not work, as `setName` is declared to return a `Child1`, which *does not have* a `setBirthdate` method.

### Putting it together

```
import java.util.function.*;

interface Grandparent<G extends Grandparent<G>> {
  @SuppressWarnings({"all", "unchecked"})
  default G self() {
    return (G) this;
  }

  default G apply(Consumer<? super G> consumer) {
    consumer.accept(self());
    return self();
  }
}

interface Parent1<P extends Parent1<P>> extends Grandparent<P> {}
interface Parent2<P extends Parent2<P>> extends Grandparent<P> {}

class Child implements Parent1<Child>, Parent2<Child> {
  String name;
}

class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child c = new Child();
    c.name = "Jake";
    Consumer<Object> printer = System.out::println;
    Consumer<Child> announcer = x -> System.out.println("Welcome to the world, " + x.name + "!!");
    Child d = c.apply(printer);
    Child e = c.apply(announcer);
    assert c == d;
    assert c == e;
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be an article in JavaWorld or Oracle's Java blog.

Comment: There goes my CameraGun... Jokes aside, my use-case matches option 2 (semantically equivalent methods). Ironically, I already had the proposed solution implemented elsewhere in my API so it was easy for me to re-apply it here. Great minds think alike. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest you this, for starting on something that compiles.
But is it near enough of what you're willing?

```java
import java.util.function.Consumer;

interface GrandParent {
   default GrandParent apply(Consumer<GrandParent> consumer) {
      consumer.accept(this);
      return this;
   }
}

interface Parent1 extends GrandParent {
   default Parent1 apply(Consumer<GrandParent> consumer) {
      consumer.accept(this);
      return this;
   }
}

interface Parent2 extends GrandParent {
   default Parent2 apply(Consumer<GrandParent> consumer) {
      consumer.accept(this);
      return this;
   }
}

interface Child extends Parent1, Parent2 {
   @Override
   default Child apply(Consumer<GrandParent> consumer) {
      consumer.accept(this);
      return this;
   }
}
```

Comment: It won't work in my case because there are multiple children of different types. I'll update the question with the workaround I ended up using for now.